# function parameter undefined in knockout.js

Tags: function, knockout.js, design-patterns, undefined, revealing-module-pattern

I am using the Revealing Module Pattern to get some structure in my knockout.js code.
It is a very simple Example
Goal: return the value of the Name-Property of the Object.
Problem: The function parameter x is undefined.

http://jsfiddle.net/ThomasDeutsch/8hzhp/

What exactly is the problem here?
Help me fiddle this one out please.

Comment: Solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873214/knockout-js-function-parameter-undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution. 
The Problem was that i have not defined a function. ko.computed will not do the job. So this is the solution:
[Knockout.js: Function parameter undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873214/knockout-js-function-parameter-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should write

```
x.Name
```

instead of

```
x.getElementsByName('Name')
```

since I do not see where x should obtain this method from, as x is not an element of the document tree. But I am not an expert on this.

Ok, this works for me:

```
// My Model
function Customer(id, name, lastname) {
    this.Id = ko.observable(id);
    this.Name = ko.observable(name);
    this.LastName = ko.observable(lastname);
}

// My ViewModel
ViewModel = (function () {
    var customer = new Customer(1, "Thomas", "D")
    var getName = ko.computed(function () {
        return customer.Name ();
    })
    ;
    return {
        getName: getName
    };
})();

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

The getName in the return statement must be a function, not the result of a function. Probably the framework (which I do not know) calls the function (without arguments) in order to obtain the value.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not helping. The problem is that x is undefined - and i do not know why. Btw. x.Name would return the observable function. x.Name() is maybe the right call.

Comment: This was my solution. Than i wanted to have more reusable code - so i moved the customer out of the function and replaced it with the x property. so i can use every object with a Name-Property to use this function. This is a best practice i need to have.