# Knockout.js: Function parameter undefined

Tags: javascript, parameters, knockout.js, undefined, revealing-module-pattern

I have a very simple example that is not working.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ThomasDeutsch/8hzhp/3/

```
// My Model
function Customer(id, name, lastname) {
    this.Id = ko.observable(id);
    this.Name = ko.observable(name);
    this.LastName = ko.observable(lastname);
}

// My ViewModel
ViewModel = (function () {
    var getName = ko.computed(function (x) {
        return x.Name();
    });

    return {
        getName: getName(new Customer(1, "Thomas", "D"))
    };
})();

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);​
```

**problem:** parameter (x) is undefined

**goal:** return the Name-Property of the called Object - i want to use the x as a property so that i can call this function with any Object with a observable Name property

*Code explanation:
This is done using the revealing-module-pattern with knockout.js. The Name-property is a ko.observable() - so the () is needed.*

**question**: Why is x undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me ask you.  Where do you think x is defined?

You are calling getName and passing a Customer, but getName doesn't expect a parameter.

If you rewrite your function like this it will work:

```
var getName = function(x) { return ko.computed( function() {
    return x.Name();
})};
```

Comment: Now i get it! Tank you. I thought hat i could use the ko.computed function as a sort of reference. Ok since the Name property is already a ko.observable function i do not need the ko.computed -> result: http://jsfiddle.net/ThomasDeutsch/8hzhp/6/

Comment: As you are now returning an observable you can also remove the () and just do: `return x.Name;`.  The text binding knows how to work with the observable.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to change the value of the observable "getName", but since it's a computed one, that's undefined behavior until you specify how this should be handled.

I think the best solution would be to introduce another observable that stores the customer.

```
var ViewModel = (function() {
    // Observable for the customer
    var customer = ko.observable(new Customer(1, "Thomas", "D"));

    // The computed observable, using the other one
    var getName = ko.computed(function() {
        return customer().Name();
    });

    // If you only need to access the name, its sufficient
    // to export only that observable. However, this is still
    // read-only.
    return {
        getName: getName
    };
})();
```

If you want to make it writable, you can define a setter for the computed observable:

```
var getName = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        return customer().Name();
    },
    write: function(n) {
        customer().Name(n);
    }
});
```

(not an example that makes the most sense, but that is because you don't really need a computed observable here)